# how to upload complete excel file into server using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**Code**

**template**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    async onChange(event) {
      const headers = {
          'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
       const response = await.post('http://localhost:3030/api/new/post', event.target.files[0], headers);
       console.log(response);
    },
  }
};
```

I would like to upload file as it is through api, I tested through postman it does work. How can I upload it via VueJS. can anyone suggest.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FormData` to send files to the server.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    async onChange(event) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", event.target.files[0]);
      const response = await axios.post("xyzzy.com", formData);
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```